# Depurar un ENTRY

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hola a todos y gracias de desde ahora.
Me gustaría saber si puedo depurar un `Entry` con la nomenclatura del punto como hago con los `Label`, ejemplo:

```
Label(myFrame,text="Apellido: ", bg="blue", fg="yellow").grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")
```

pero pasa que a los `Label` solo le pongo el `.grid` pero a los `Entry` me sería útil ponerle también un `.config` después de la sintaxys del `.grid` y me salta un error, aquí les dejo la sintaxis completa por si alguien me puede ayudar.

```
Label(myFrame,text="Apellido: ", bg="blue", fg="yellow").grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")
apellido=StringVar()
Entry(myFrame, textvariable=apellido).grid(row=2, column=1).config(justify="center", fg="black")
```

Aquí termina esa parte del código.

De nuevo mil gracias a todos por solo fijarse en mi pregunta.

Comment: Hola Lennier.py, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. En la pregunta marcada como duplicada se explica porqué pasa esto. Es un Frame pero el problema es el mismo. Debes usar una variable para mantener una referencia al widget y usarla para llamar a los métodos `grid`, `config`, o lo que sea: `entry = Entry(myFrame, ...)`; `entry.grid(row=2, column=1)`; `entry.config(justify="center", fg="black")`. Si tienes alguna duda comenta. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias FJSevilla por tu aclaración y por la modificacion de la pregunta, es q soy novato usando Stack Overflow y no se mucho todavia a la hora de formular las preguntas. Gracias por la ayuda. Un saludo.

Comment: De nada, no te preocupes ya irás aprendiendo como funciona el sitio. Por cierto, para formatear las líneas de código adecuadamente solo tienes que seleccionarlas y pulsar el botón `{}` del editor o `Ctrl` + `k`.

Comment: De nuevo mil gracias, me sorprende la utilidad de este sitio, había oído hablar de él pero nunca me imaginé la disposición a ayudar a las personas que tienen los demás usuarios, gracias a eso y en parte a tu ayuda seguiré usándolo.